# How to make a countdown timer with a slider

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, timer

In my game I have a slider that represents the amount of time left and the time left goes down by 1 every second this is what I have come up with but it the *slider does not go down except the first time* can someone help me fix my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float time = 100;
    public float totalTime = 100;
    public float duration = 1;

    public Slider slider;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        time = totalTime;
        slider.value = time;
        StartCoroutine(CountDown());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    IEnumerator CountDown()
    {
        if (time > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
            time -= 1;
            slider.value = time;
            yield return CountDown();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Solved:

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeLeft;
    public float maxTime = 100f;
    public float duration = 1;

    public Slider slider;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        timeLeft = maxTime;
        slider.value = timeLeft;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (timeLeft > 0)
        {
            timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
            slider.value = timeLeft / maxTime;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need a more precise problem description then "Does not Work".

Comment: @Christopher ok i changed the description

Comment: @Christopher are you going to help me with my code please

Comment: @JonBergeron - Is this edit to your code in your question your solution?

Comment: @JonBergeron Please add your solution as an answer. Don't edit your question to show it.

Comment: @ModusTollens - I've partially fixed it. The OP should now edit out the answer and post it separately.

Comment: @JonBergeron Could you please copy and cut the answer from the question and paste it in the answer section? You can even accept your own answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand completely how coroutines and yield return work.

In easy words coroutines always leaves at the yield return allowing the next frame to be started but let's say remembering where it left. In the next frame it will go on at the point where it left.

So in case you want to use the coroutines instead of simply doing it in `update` as already suggested you have e.g. these two options:

1. A coroutine has to be called by `StartCoroutine()`. So instead of your line

   ```c#
   yield return Countdown();
   ```

   you'ld have to use

   ```c#
   StartCoroutine(Countdown());
   ```
2. As said before a coroutine continues at the point it left so instead of if else and a kind of recursive call you could just use a while loop:

   ```c#
   IEnumerator Countdown()
   {
       while(time > 0)
       {
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
           time -= duration;
           slider.value = time;

           // This leaves the coroutine at this point
           // so in the next frame the while loop continues
           yield return null;
       }
   }
   ```